# bash script does not work when called on jee

Tags: linux, bash, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jee

i have a script bash which requires parameters.

when i call it directly from putty, it works, hen i do from my jee program it does not work and does not show me any errors.

This is my java code:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"sudo", "ssh", "-tt", "root@89.40.112.248", "/root/dve", "-l", "89.40.112.120,89.40.112.248", "you.mp4", "-s",".teeeest.avi" };

List<ObjectNode> listFileNode = new ArrayList<ObjectNode>(); 

try{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray);
        Process proc = pb.start();     // Start the process.
        System.out.println("Script executing");
        rc= proc.waitFor();    // Wait for the process to finish.
        System.out.printf("Script executed successfully in ", rc);

 InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String line = null;
                    System.out.println("<ERROR___EXEC>");
                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){

                        System.out.println(line);
                        node.put("line",line );
                        listFileNode.add(node);
                      }
                    System.out.println("</ERROR___EXEC>");
                    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
                    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);


                    InputStream processInputStream =proc.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(processInputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    System.out.println("<RESULTAT___EXEC>"); 
                    while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                        System.out.println(line);
                        node.put("lineR",line );
                        listFileNode.add(node);

                  } 
                    System.out.println("</RESULTAT___EXEC>");  

            }catch (Throwable t)
              {
                t.printStackTrace();
              }
```

please help me i am stuck on this from a week and i don't find solution

Comment: Please only enough code here necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi, the java code i put was my spring controller and the script i want to run is available here: https://github.com/nergdron/dve

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sudo` command in the java code. If you need to run root privileged application you need to switch to root before running your java code.

If you want to do it from your java code, you need to call [`setuid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html). But I don't know you can call `setuid` from a java code. For that purpose you may need a C/C++ wrapper for switching to root. Refer:[http://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) question for writing wrapper.